# Wordpress: Is it possible to use post-type as part of a css selector in block editor stylesheet?

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, gutenberg-blocks

I created a Wordpress theme and now I am working on an editor-stylesheet for the block editor to better reflect the look of the theme in the editor. For this, I need to be able to address different post types in there.

For the frontend, there is the `body_class()` function to be used in templates, which inserts - among others - a class which identifies the post-type and can be used in combined selectors to adress certain elements only in a particular post-type.

Now, the post-type class *is* in the body tag of the page, also in edit mode, but apparently the editor-stylesheet CSS is applied in a kind of "isolated" way – combined selectors which contain classes that are in the body tag won't work in the editor.

So I am looking for something similar which would work in the block editor, so that I can use it in combined selectors which only apply to certain elements in a particular post-type.

Any ideas how to do that?

---

BTW, I also tried to check the post-type using Javascript/jQuery:

```
wp.domReady(function() {
        var postType = jQuery('form.metabox-base-form input#post_type').attr('value');
        if(postType == 'post'){
            alert("It's a post!");//in real life some other action...
        }
});
```

But although it would be logical to at least trigger the alert I put in there, nothing happens when I load the edit page of a post, where that input element including its "post" value is clearly present. (?)

---

Addition: Trying everything I can think of to find a workaround solution, I also  tried this script to just see if I can check for body classes at all when I am using the editor:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    if(jQuery('body').hasClass('post-type-page')) {
        alert("It's a page!");
    } else {
        alert("It's not a page");
    }
});
```

The result on editor pages (i.e. the *web page* displaying the WP block editor): No alert at all! Why that??? Does the block editor Javascript block/prevent all other Javascript?

---

P.S.: I posted the first part of this question on StackExchange WordPress development before, but got no reactions at all, so i am trying it here...

Comment: When I run your javascript code block in the console window of Chrome I get the right alert that `"It's a page!"` Can you edit your post to show us how you're queuing the scripts and styles you want to appear on the admin page edit screens?

Comment: @JobiWon9178 Did you get that alert when you were loading a page in the (block) editor? Because that's what I am talking about. The alert *does* appear when I open/view the page, but it doesn't when I open the page in the editor - any browser, and that's where I need it (in edit mode). BTW, I put that script at the very bottom of my `functions.php` file, and the CSS I am talking about is in the stylesheet I defined as editor stylesheet for the block editor (which otherwise works fine)

Comment: I am talking about the block editor, yes. You might need to add the script via the [`admin_enqueue_scripts`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/admin_enqueue_scripts/) hook, because scripts loaded for a site's front end are not generally loaded on the back-end admin side.

Comment: For what it's worth, perhaps [this guide](https://rudrastyh.com/gutenberg/css.html) might help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a solution myself (but with a hint from @JobiWon9178 - thank you!!!). Not pure CSS, but involving some JS/jQuery. It's a script similar to the one I already posted in the question, with the necessary additions to add classes to relevant HTML elements dynamically:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if($('body').hasClass('post-type-page')) {
        $('#editor').addClass('post-type-page');
    } else if($('body').hasClass('post-type-post')) {
        $('#editor').addClass('post-type-post');
    }
});
```

This adds the relevant `post-type-xxxx` class to the `#editor` DIV, which is one of the outer containers of the block editor. Contrary to the `body` classes, the classes of this element *are* relevant for the editor contents and can be used in combined selectors in the editor stylsheet.

(Note: Initially I tried to add the class to the wrapper DIV which has the classes `edit-post-visual-editor editor-styles-wrapper`, but that wouldn't work - the post-type class simply didn't get added.)

An example: The following CSS rule in the editor stylesheet will now apply to all paragraph blocks in the editor, but only when the post-type is a page:

```
.post-type-page .wp-block-paragraph {
   /* (CSS settings here) */
}
```

An important detail, which @JobiWon9178 pointed out in a comment: The jQuery script above has to be added using [admin_enqueue_scripts](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/admin_enqueue_scripts/) , not together with the scripts for the frontend. So I put that script into a file called `admin_scripts.js` and enqueued that as follows in `functions.php`:

```
function my_admin_scripts($hook) {
    if ( 'post.php' != $hook ) {
        return;
    }
    wp_register_script('adminscripts', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/admin_scripts.js', '', null, true);
    wp_enqueue_script('adminscripts');
}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'my_admin_scripts' );
```

So that's my working solution. If someone still comes up with a pure CSS solution, I'd be very happy, but I guess for now (i.e. in Wordpress 5.3) there is no CSS-only method for this.

Comment: "Contrary to the body classes, the classes of this element are relevant" 

Do you know why the body isn't relevant to css? I understand that it's not, but is this behavior intentional or do you know the cause?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to do this with purely CSS. Are you sure your CSS is getting added correctly?

```
add_action('admin_head', 'my_custom_fonts');
function my_custom_fonts() {
      echo '<style>
              .post-type-page .wp-block-paragraph {
                   font-size: 5rem;
               }
      </style>';
 }
```

If I go into the editor this paragraph text is only modified under a page.

This is running WP 5.3.2.

add_editor_style is technically used for custom TinyMCE.

Using enqueue_block_editor_assets was added in WP 5.0 to add styles and functionality to blocks.

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/enqueue_block_editor_assets/

Edit:
CSS only version

```php
function custom_block_editor_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'legit-editor-styles', get_theme_file_uri( '/css/style-editor.css' ), false, '1.0', 'all' );
}
add_action( 'enqueue_block_editor_assets', 'custom_block_editor_styles' );
```

Comment: That's interesting: When you insert a `style` tag using `admin_head` as you did, it does work indeed. However, the same CSS rule doesn't work if I put it into my editor stylesheet, which definitley *is* getting added, since all the other CSS rules in there work. Strange behaviour... But with "pure CSS" I really meant using the editor stylesheet, not using a PHP function to add a style tag dynamically. Nevertheless: Thanks a lot for your answer!

Comment: hmm, how are you adding the style stylesheet?

Comment: With these two lines in functions.php: `add_theme_support( 'editor-styles' );
add_editor_style( 'gb_editor_styles.css' );`

Comment: I would actually change to using this.

add_action( 'enqueue_block_editor_assets', 'legit_block_editor_styles' );

and add your own stylesheet.

add_editor_style was added in WP 3.4 for TinyMCE editor stylesheets.

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_editor_style/

Comment: Hmm - Right here, add_editor_style is listed as the "official" way: https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/developers/themes/theme-support/#enqueuing-the-editor-style But I'll try what you recommended - thanks!

Comment: Ya, I thought that was interesting as well. I went digging in the twentytwenty theme where they actually use:

add_action( 'enqueue_block_editor_assets', 'twentytwenty_block_editor_styles', 1, 1 );